# How to read dictionary list from socket connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, nsdictionary

Whats the right way to read the dictionaries from socket data of the form:

```
{"data": {"abc": [], "pqr": []}, "error": ""}{"data": {"abc": [], "pqr": []}, "error": ""}{"data": {"abc": [], "pqr": []}, "error": ""}{"data": {"abc": [], "pqr": []}, "error": ""}{"data": {"abc": [], "pqr": []}, "error": ""}
```

Notice there are independent json dictionaries and we need to convert that into list of dictionaries. We can always do so using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method by replacing "}{". But is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that you already put string-dictionary in a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary* jsonSocketData;

for(NSDictionary* data in jsonSocketData[@"data"]) {
   /* whatever */
   NSLog(@"%@", data[@"abc"]); 
}
```

By the way I hope result of your request is more like this:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "data": {
                "abc": [],
                "pqr": []
            },
            "error": ""
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "abc": [],
                "pqr": []
            },
            "error": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

If you have to convert your NSString (json) to NSDictionary:

```
NSString* jsonString = @"..";

NSData* data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

## Edit

If string you posted is the exact string that you receive I would this trick (in this way the json will be well-formed):

```
NSString* response = @"...";
/* only if you are sure about format */
response = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"}{" withString:@"},{"];
/* otherwise you can apply regex, defintely more flexible, with pattern "}(.?){" */
response = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"result\":[%@]}", response];
```

After this trick, you can apply code above.
Btw, in my opinion, best way is to have a well-formed json rather than apply boring and custom parsing.

Comment: Please look at the data carefully. The format is {}{}{} at the other most layer. Now the challenge is to read it as an array of dictionary without a hack.

Comment: So, when you take the request, response is a string "json-fake" like string you posted?

Comment: There is no issue in reading the data. Formatting is the challenge. What I am looking to do is convert the above mentioned data in the following format [{"data": {"abc": [], "pqr": []}, "error": ""}, {"data": {"abc": [], "pqr": []}, "error": ""}, {"data": {"abc": [], "pqr": []}, "error": ""}] . Notice the braces carefully.

Comment: This will not solve problem because we cannot distinguish between two dictionaries. It will still be treated as one object rather than a list.

Comment: And the above recommended json format cannot be used if you are using a socket because we get large amount of data in chucks and each of these is a json itself.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood question, I don't see that "," are missing. So, you you are sure that string that arrive has "}{" you can add it with "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString"

Comment: Thats what I had in mind. But since the data is very large in size its not the most efficient way because it will run a check on entire data. But thats what I'm using right now until I get a better solution.

Comment: You also apply a regex (more flexible) with pattern "}(.?){", but for speed up read of your data I think that there is not to much to do. An approach could be "divide" result paginating the response server side. https://regex101.com/r/gA3sE6/1

Comment: Thanks Velthune. As a quick solution I'll use "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString" but in a long run we will move to pagination.

Answer (score -1):

```
var dictionary = ["key" : "value", "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "Key3" : "Value3"]

for (key, value) in companies 
{
    println("\(value)")
}
```